# Finding the point of intersection of L and the xy-plane.

Tags: linear-algebra

$$P = (-1, 1, 1)$$
$$Q = (1,2,3)$$
$$R = (2,1,0)$$

---

My textbook provides a solution to this, but I'm unclear of how it came to it. The book says;

In the xy-plane we have $0 = z = 1 + 2λ$ so $λ = \frac{-1}{2}$ and so the intersection of `L` with the `xy-plane` is $(-2, \frac{1}{2}, 0)$

Can someone explain where `z = 1+2λ` comes from, as well as how the final answer is arrived at?

EDIT: I believe that the line L = (-1, 1, 1) + λ(2,1,2)

Comment: Is the question about guessing what $L$ is for the answer to be $(-2,1/2,0)$? Seriously, you forgot to define $L$.

Comment: No the answer is that the line L intersects the xy-plane at (-2, \frac{1}{2}, 0).

EDIT: L isn't given in the question, only the points are.

Comment: You havee given three points, which are not collinear.  What is $L$?  The line through two of them?

Comment: It doesn't say in the question, but from a previous part I got that the line is: (-1, 1, 1) + λ(2,1,2). I'm going to assume that's the one that they refer to.

Comment: You need only two points to find the equation of line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $L$ is $(-1,1,1)+\lambda (2,1,2)$ and we want the intersection with the $xy$ plane, we need to find the point on $L$ where $z=0$, which is the $xy$ plane.  The general point on the line is then $(-1+2 \lambda, 1+ \lambda, 1+2 \lambda)$.  The third coordinate is $z$ so we set that to zero, $1+2 \lambda = 0$.  Solving, $\lambda =-\frac 12$ so we plug that into the general point we get $(-1+2(-\frac 12),1+(-\frac 12),1+2(-\frac 12))=(-2,\frac 12,0)$

Answer (score 3):

Since we want to find the intersection of $L$ and the $xy$-plane, let us recall the most important fact about points in the $xy$-plane: they have a $z$ coordinate of $0$ (this stems from the fact that the $xy$-plane is defined as the points with a z coordinate of $0$). Thus, if we look at line $L=(-1, 1, 1) + λ(2,1,2)=(-1+2λ, 1+λ, 1+2λ)$, we want to see at what $λ$ will $L$ have a $z$ coordinate of $0$.

Thus, we set $1+2λ=0$, as $1+2λ$ is the $z$ coordinate of line $L$, and solve for $λ$. Since we want to know what point this is at, we plug $λ=-\frac{1}{2}$ into the original equation for line $L$.